# JPanel Padding in Java

Tags: java, swing, formatting, jpanel

I have a formatting question for my Java swing application. It should be fairly straightforward, but I am having difficulty finding any aid (Every topic seems to be regarding **removing** any default padding in JPanel).

The text in my various JPanels hug the sides and top, touching the colored borders: how can I add padding?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Set an `EmptyBorder` around your `JPanel`.
Example:

```
JPanel p =new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

Comment: or you can have some extra padding arround the existing border: `p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10),  new EtchedBorder()));`

Comment: What happens when the Window is resized? This solution is not good then is it?

Comment: @Synox Legend indeed! Note that you can put EmptyBorder as last parameter for internal padding

Answer (score 4):

When you need padding inside the `JPanel` generally you add padding with the layout manager you are using.  There are cases that you can just expand the border of the `JPanel`.

Comment: Adding padding to the layout manager (In my case, GridLayout) adds padding in between the adjacent panels, but not within an individual panel. But a border will do, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I will suppose your JPanel contains JTextField, for the sake of the demo.

Those components provides [`JTextComponent#setMargin()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29) method which seems to be what you're looking for.

If you're looking for an empty border of any size around your text, well, use [`EmptyBorder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel p=new JPanel();  
GridBagLayout layout=new GridBagLayout(); 
p.setLayout(layout); 
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
gbc.gridx=0;   
gbc.gridy=0;   
p2.add("",gbc);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).