# Add space around a JPanel in a JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border, jdialog

I'm building dynamic JDialogs. I have some JPanels, and when you choose a menu option I create a modal JDialog, add a JPanel and display it:

```
JDialog dlg = new JDialog(this, title, true);
dlg.getContentPane().add(panel);
dlg.pack();
dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dlg.setVisible(true);
```

My app is working well, but there is no space between JDialog's border and the added panel, and it looks very "full/stretched" (I'm sorry, I don't know how to say this). Maybe the problem is that I'm calling JDialog.pack(), but at runtime I don't know the size of the panel, so I create the JDialog without dimensions, and after adding the content I pack it.

And my question is: What can I do to add some space around the panel?

One possible solution is adding a BorderLayout, putting the panel at center, and 4 fixed size panels at each side... But this seems an ugly hack...

Comment: [A wild URL appears!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328405/jpanel-padding-in-java)

Comment: For more general solutions to crammed space problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874717/providing-white-space-in-a-swing-gui

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply [add an empty border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) to your panel:

```
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```