# How to align text position for two different components?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to align the position of text within a JTextArea and a JButton, but with everything I tried, either nothing happens, or the alignment is still slightly off.

**Here is what is looks like:**
[image]
(You can see with the highlighted option that the JButton (center) is slightly lower than the two JTextAreas on either side.)

**Here is some code:**

```
                categoryFile[i][j] = tempButton;
                categoryFile[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                categoryFile[i][j].setForeground(Color.black);
                categoryFile[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                categoryFile[i][j].setFocusable(false);
                categoryFile[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);;
                categoryFile[i][j].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
                categoryFile[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,10));
                categoryFile[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        openPDFWithOptions(filePath,fileName);
                    }
                });

                JPanel listRow = new JPanel();
                listRow.setBackground(Color.white);
                listRow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                listRow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 40));

                JTextArea category = new JTextArea(fileElements[0]); 
                category.setEditable(false);
                JTextArea parent = new JTextArea(fileElements[1]);
                parent.setEditable(false);

                listRow.add(parent,BorderLayout.WEST);
                listRow.add(categoryFile[i][j],BorderLayout.CENTER);
                listRow.add(category,BorderLayout.EAST);

                categoryLists[i].add(listRow,c);
```

Right now I am using `categoryFile[i][j].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP)` to change the position of the JButton, which ALMOST works. I've also tried changing the vertical alignment of the JTextAreas, but nothing changed.

*How can I align the text within these components?*

Comment: It can be quite difficult to align the text of different components when you use a different font in the different components. Also, why are you using a JTextArea? Do you anticipate that component to have multiple lines of text? If not, you should be using a JTextField instead.

Comment: Yeah, all the different ways to display text confuse me, so I just picked one. I also didn't notice the different fonts, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way to fix this would probably be to just add some padding on the 1st and third columns to set all the text to the same height. See [Jpanel Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328405/jpanel-padding-in-java)